# Laravel returns no variable passed by the with

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello guys beauty? Because Laravel is not returning the object in view. Seeking the session I can get the data.

```
/* ProdutoController */

public function deleta($id){
    $prod = Produto::find($id);
    $prod->delete();
    return redirect()->action('ProdutoController@lista')
        ->with('message2','deletado');
}
```

View

```
@if(!empty($message2))
    Deletado com sucesso
@endif
```

Comment: You're calling another function within your `deleta` function and what does it consists can you please post that too.

Answer (score 2):

The redirect with() method flashes data to the session. It does not pass the variable directly to your view. Try the following

```
 @if(!empty(session('message2'))
    Deletado com sucesso
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check the session variable if exist.

```
@if (session()->has('message2'))
    Deletado com sucesso
@endif
```